# SQL Server 2008R2 : how to convert date for month column?

Tags: date, sql-server-2008-r2

This is my request: based on `Review Date`, populate the month of review in `MM/DD/YYYY` format. E.g. if `Review Date` is 8/17/2016, Month of Review should populate 8/1/2016.

Originally, I had it coded

```
datename(month, c.CreatedDate) as 'Month'
```

but requestor now wants it `8/1/2016` instead of 'August' regardless the day of the month.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dateadd and eomonth functions

```
dateadd(day, 1, eomonth(dateadd(month, -1, your_date)))
```

EDITED

Sorry, eomonth is available since SQL Server 2012

```
select dateadd(day, -(datepart(day, your_date))+1, CONVERT(DATE, your_date, 101))
```

Comment: the date format returned as yyyy-mm-dd instead of mm/dd/yyyy...I tried several converts and none returning the format I need?

Comment: if it's just for display purpose, you can use the FORMATMESSAGE function 

select FORMATMESSAGE('%i/1/%i', datepart(month, your_date), datepart(year, your_date))

Comment: Sorry I took a bit to response. I am not sure how to fix this error message - Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 3...FORMATMESSAGE('%i/1/%i', datepart(month, c.createddate), datepart(year, c.createddate))